# Authorization error: "Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that"

Tags: pinterest

Using this code in a browser to get the access code...

```
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/redirect.htm&client_id=appid&scope=read_public,write_public&state=768uyFys
```

I got a dialog and when I pressed OK, then I got this error:

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 12, "data": "path: /oauth/\nparams:<dict_itemiterator object at 0x7f9735706710>\nAuthError(code=500, message='dial tcp 127.0.0.1:22000: connect: connection refused')", "message": "Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that.", "endpoint_name": "oauth_connect"}
```

Comment: Having the same issue with my app (it worked just fine before). As the error message suggests, it seems like there's some issue on pinterest's side

Answer (score 0):

I also faced an issue like this. You can paste the URL on google browser and copy the redirect_url and add the same in the Pinterest app. Pinterest will call the redirect URL after hitting the API. You can add logs in your application where the redirect URL is hitting to verify the response.

```
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?state=9750187663&scope=read_public&client_id=abc&redirect_uri=https://9fa6caa3.ngrok.io/laravel/public/pinToken&response_type=code
```

You will get the result
array (
  'state' => '9750187663',
  'code' => '15a1bcfb012abc1',
)